# Global Hadoop configuration storage

Tags: java, hadoop

Is there any way to set / get global Hadoop configuration object, something like pseudocode below? Of course I can create my own class with static methods which do what I need but its better if something like this could be found inside Hadoop Java API to not make dependencies more complex. By now I did not find anything usable. Any advice?

In some application level configurator.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(...);
<something>.SetGlobalConfig(conf);
```

In lower layer client code.

```
Configuration conf = <something>.GetGlobalConfig();
// ... something that needs configuration.
```

UPDATE 1: I know about Hadoop .xml configuration files and actually it's one of possible solutions but it's preferable to have all configuration done in code, without external files.

UPDATE 2: Based on points provided decision is to use 'usual' .xml configuration packaged together with job code. Client can 'tune' some parameters via command line parameters that keep hadoop-like semantic due to usage of the same Tool. To isolate rest of code from Hadoop configuration / user aspects even more application code requests configuration through special COnfigurator singletone.

Original question is considered solved though I don't mind against useful ideas.

Comment: To be honest, configuration in code is bad style as you need to recompile your project in order to make config changes. If you insist doing that in code, you have to write it for your own, because Hadoop doesn't provide this in-code facility.

Comment: Good argument. Probably I'll take this solution but let me some time to find useful packaging scheme.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can set these config settings from the command line with `-Dfoo=bar` options, another reason not to override them in code.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl and this combination seems to give me full range of variants because I can use things like Tool and overload arguments in code if critically needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
```

it will look into the classpath of your project for `core-default.xml` and `core-site.xml`.

And the `core-site.xml` is exactly where you want to put your "global" configurations into.